# theme wrapper not working

Tags: theming

I added theme wrapper to main menu using page_preprocess but its not addde class to ul of menu.

Here is my code

```
function semanticUI_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
$variables['primary_nav'] = FALSE;
  if ($variables['main_menu']) {
    // Build links.
    $variables['primary_nav'] = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
    // Provide default theme wrapper function.
    $variables['primary_nav']['#theme_wrappers'] = array('menu_tree__primary');
  }
}

function semanticUI_menu_tree__primary(&$variables) {
  print'<pre>';print_r($variables);die();
  return '<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: What you want to override? You want another wrapper element on primary menu or just adding another class to UL ?

Comment: I just want to add classes to ul i m making a base theme on semantic ui framework.